# Цикл Ajax запросов и возможность отловить ошибку с прекращением выполнения цикла

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем привет!

У меня есть таблица с которой я работаю, из нее я получаю массив ID для обработки данных.
Я хочу в цикле отправлять ajax - запросы, и в случае ошибки прекратить выполнение цикла.

пример:

```
let user_id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

user_id.forEach(id => {
getUser(id);
});
function getUser(user_id){
    BX.rest.callMethod('user.get', {
        id: user_id
      },
      function(res) {
          if (res.error()) {
              // error message
          } else {
              //success
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let user_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function getUser(index) {
  if (index >= user_ids.length)
    return;
  BX.rest.callMethod('user.get', { id: user_ids[index] }, function(res) {
    if (res.error()) {
      // error message
    } else {
      //success
      getUser(index + 1);
    }
  });
}

getUser(0);
```